# Do I have to pay a fee to distribute a paid app

Tags: ios

Do I have to pay a fee to distribute a paid app to the app store (iOS). (I already have a developer membership with apple)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't have to pay a fee when distributing a new paid app through the App Store, but Apple will only give you 70% of the sales revenue.

So the upload doesn't cost a fee, but from what the user pays for your app you will get only 70%. See here for more details: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html

Answer (score 2):

Paid developer account is required to be in the App Store, that's $99/yr. Then Apple retains 30% of your app's sales. You should read about it here, https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html